# Why doesn't setter get called when using property() function?

Tags: python, getter-setter, python-2.x, accessor

I have the following simple python class that defines a getter and setter using the `property` function:

```
class MyClass():

    def get_my_var(self):
        print "In get_my_var()"
        return None

    def set_my_var(self, value):
        print "In set_my_var()"
        return

    my_var = property(get_my_var, set_my_var)
```

When I instantiate this class and use the getter it works just fine as expected:

```
>>> x = MyClass()
>>> print "x.my_var = %s" % x.my_var
In get_my_var()
x.my_var = None
```

However, when I then try to use the setter, it seemingly doesn't get called at all. The print statement from within the setter never fires:

```
>>> print "About to do 'x.my_var = 5'"
About to do 'x.my_var = 5'
>>> x.my_var = 5
>>>
```

Why does the getter work but not the setter? Why isn't there any error? And how do I get the setter to work as [**advertised**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties need to be on ***new style*** classes to work properly.  Don't forget to inherit from `object`!

```
class MyClass(object):  # !
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a new-style class:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def get_my_var(self):
        print "In get_my_var()"
        return None

    def set_my_var(self, value):
        print "In set_my_var()"
        return

    my_var = property(get_my_var, set_my_var)
```

In Python 3, new style classes are the only style you can use, but you're clearly using 2.x (`print` is a statement).  To get new-style semantics, you must inherit from `object`.